# How to create a c++ enum from a C style #define and struct (or what's the right way to do this)?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm working with a C library ([Raylib](https://www.raylib.com/)) that uses the following for color representation:

```
#define RED        { 230, 41, 55, 255 }

// Color type, RGBA (32bit)
typedef struct Color {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char a;
} Color;
```

I want to define an enum of all the `Color` objects that I will use in my palette in my `C++` code.

But `enum class` only allows integral kinds of values. What's the best way to have a fixed static set of values which are non-integral?

One approach I have in mind is just declare `static constexpr` values in a `struct`. Is this the right approach?

```
struct Color {
  constexpr static auto MYRED = RED;
  constexpr static auto MYBLUE = BLUE;
  constexpr static auto MYGREEN = GREEN;
};
```

Comment: I don't really think there is a *proper* approach here, it depends on the coding style you use. You could use enum class if you want, just change ``Color`` to a union with an integer member. Personally I prefer, in this case, defining them as static in the structure itself so you would access it via ``Color::Red``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace RayLib {
  using Color = ::Color;
  inline constexpr Color Red = RED;
  inline constexpr Color Blue = BLUE;
  inline constexpr Color Green = GREEN;
}
```

is how I would do it.

You might also want:

```
namespace MyApp {
  inline constexpr std::array Palette = {
    RayLib::Red,
    RayLib::Blue,
    RayLib::Green,
    RayLib::Fuscia
  };
}
```

where `MyApp` is the namespace you are using for app-specific code (in this case, the palette you are using in your app).  (Apologies if I didn't get the deduction syntax quite right above)

Comment: I feel like `inline constexpr` would make more sense here, but otherwise it's fine.

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach. Since these are global variables, do you use it in the same namespace as the rest of the code? Or is the RayColors a different namespace?

Comment: @PlastyGrove That is your C++ namespace for functions that help you interact with `RayLib`.  You could alse use `namespace RayLib`.  Basically, don't pollute the global namespace more than you have to.  It also means you can name `RayLib::Red` if it would be confusing.  Updated with `inline` and changed namespace to `RayLib`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Thank you, this is very clear and I'll use this in my code. A related question, how do I declare the colors in a header file? I would like to `#include "raylib.h"` only in the `.cpp` file. I can forward declare `struct Color` in the `.h` file, but I can't seem to be able to assign `RED` or any color in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Seems I can do it if I use a `extern const Color` instead of `constexpr`. Is that the right way?

Comment: @PlastyGrove I assumed you wanted "macro level" replacement -- a `constexpr` must be fully defined to all users, which in theory lets the compiler always know what the value is at every point of use.  `extern const` isn't the same as a macro, but yes it might be what you want.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Yes sorry, I developed a bit more on what I wanted after I posted the question. But your answer set me on the right track, thank you so much!