# Cannot forward declare a C typedef struct - looking for alternative suggestions

Tags: c++, c++17

I am using a third-party C library ([Raylib](https://raylib.com)) which has macros and `struct` defined as follows in the header:

```
// raylib.h
#define RED { 230, 41, 55, 255 }     // Red

// Color type, RGBA (32bit)
typedef struct Color {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char a;
} Color;
```

I want to encapsulate this in my own `C++` header and source file called `engine.h` and `engine.cc` which expose only the relevant functions and macros.

To ensure that only `engine.cc` has access to the header `raylib.h`, I would ideally like to:

1. Forward declare the `struct Color` in `engine.h` and
2. `#include "raylib.h"` only in `engine.cc`

Something like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58636700/1287554)):

```
// engine.h
// Forward declare.
struct Color;
typedef struct Color Color;

namespace Engine {
  namespace Colors {
    const extern Color Red;
  }

  void SetBackgroundColor(Color color);
};

// engine.cc
#include "engine.h"
#include "raylib.h"

namespace Engine {
  namespace Colors {
    const Color Red = RED;
  }

  void SetBackgroundColor(Color color) {
    ::SetBackgroundColor(color);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because I can't forward declare the typedef since it defines the struct also within the typedef.

My question is, what is the best alternative if I want to keep `raylib.h` hidden from all the other files that include `engine.h`?

One approach that I have tried and which works is to have my own `enum class` of colors which are then resolved by a helper function which is in an anonymous namespace in `engine.cc`. The helper function resolves it using a `switch` statement. But this is tedious as I will need to write a lot of code for every new color I want to use. Also, `Color` is only one of the structs with associated macros. There are many many more and I don't want to create these helper functions for every one of them.

Comment: Why `typedef Color color`?

Comment: Your code compiles for me:https://godbolt.org/z/1XGgu1, please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles - Thanks for that. It compiles, but the `Color` in `engine.h` is different from `Color` in `engine.cc`. When you try to use `SetBackgroundColor(Engine::Colors::Red)` it will say `Cannot cast from Color to Color`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles - Regarding `typedef Color Color`, apologies, I meant to write `typedef struct Color Color`.

Comment: Concerning `struct`s (and `union`s and `enum`s), there is a difference between C and C++: In C, a `struct Color` can be used only as `struct Color`. Hence, the `typedef struct Color { } Color;` for convenience. In C++, `struct Color` can be used as `Color`. The identifier of `struct` becomes the name of the type - much more convenient (IMHO). Hence, such `typedef`s like in C are not needed in C++.

Comment: `typedef struct Color Color;` defines an incomplete type (in C and C++). That can be used e.g. with pointers but not as members nor can members of the `struct` itself accessed - there are non known.

Comment: @Scheff - I see, thanks for explaining. That makes a lot of sense. Hence I'm seeing the `incomplete type` error. What should be way to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: About the incomplete type, you cannot do much. If you want to use the type you have to provide the complete definition e.g. by including the correct header. Mixing C and C++ can cause some special issues but is possible in general.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, but defining my own `struct Color` in a namespace which is identical to the one from `raylib.h` and creating a helper function that converts one to the other in `engine.cc`.

```
// engine.h

namespace Engine {
namespace Colors {
struct Color {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char a;
};

extern const Color Red;
extern const Color Green;
extern const Color Blue;
extern const Color Black;

}  // namespace Colors

void SetBackgroundColor(const Colors::Color);
}  // namespace Engine




// engine.cc

namespace Engine {
using RayColor = ::Color;
namespace Colors {
const Color Red = RED;
const Color Green = GREEN;
const Color Blue = BLUE;
const Color Black = BLACK;

namespace {
RayColor GetRayColor(const Color color) {
  return RayColor{color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a};
}
}  // namespace
}  // namespace Colors

void SetBackgroundColor(const Colors::Color color) {
  ::ClearBackground(Colors::GetRayColor(color));
}
}  // namespace Engine
```

This works because I can easily convert from `Engine::Colors::Color` to `Color`. Also because all the color macros are just numbers in braces, I can easily use them to assign to my own struct.

Of course, this solution is specific to `raylib.h` and my requirement. I wish there were a more general solution to this issue.

I am not sure how badly this approach will hit performance, but I'll try it out for now and re-visit if it breaks anything.

Comment: IMO this is over-complicating the issue and just creating future headaches for people (including yourself) trying to read the code later and wondering why the f someone would do this

Comment: @M.M - I agree with you. I wish I didn't have to do this. But for now, it's the best option I can think of. I'm open to alternatives, except having to include `raylib.h` in the header `engine.h`.

Comment: _I wish there were a more general solution to this issue._  C++20 will introduce **modules** which (I hope) will be a more general solution.

Comment: @Eljay - I had a look at modules, not sure if they will help in this case. The only way this will be resolved is if I can forward declare a type and a variable without full definition (not just a pointer or reference to the forward declared type).